# Assigning function to variable in Python

Tags: python

I have a function that returns a tuple.

```
    def x():
        ...
        return (a, b, c, d)
    var = x()
    print (var[1], var[2])
```

In this case, is the function called each time I use one of the tuple objects? 
My hopes are that the function is only called once, at the time of the assignment to variable.

Sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your function is only called once. Likewise, your `tuple` is only created once, that is at the call `var = x()`.

`var[2]` simply accesses the already **existing** tuple`s entry at a particular position, here third position (counting starts at 0).

Answer (score 0):

The function is executed only once, when you call it, specifically in this line:

```
var = x()
```

In your next line, you are just working with the `var` variable that function output was assigned to.